# Python3: How the start parameter in enumerate function works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumerate

I have a list. I want to deal with the items of the list from a `variable starting point`.

```
lines = ["line 0", ..., "line 25", ...]
cursor = 25

for i, line in enumerate(lines, start=cursor):
    print("cursor is at:", cursor)
    print("start line is:", lines[cursor])
    print("actual line is:", line)
```

Output:

```
cursor is at: 25
start line is: line 25
actual line is: line 0
...
```

I expect `enumerate` to start from `cursor`, but it starts at `0`.

---

I'm sure that I misunderstood something, but I really want to understand how `enumerate` works to improve my Python.

Comment: `enumerate` only adds a counter to an iterator, nothing more. It does not control the iteration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to understand this simple example:

```
lines = ['line 0', 'line 1', 'line 2']
cursor = 4

for idx, line in enumerate(lines, cursor):
    print(idx, '->', line)
```

Output:

```
4 -> line 0
5 -> line 1
6 -> line 2
```

**Observations:**

- `idx` starts from `cursor` (which is `4`).
- `line` starts from the beginning of `lines`, which is `lines[0]`, and not from `lines[4]`. (If it started from `lines[4]`, then it should have raised `IndexError: list index out of range` because the length of `lines` is just 3 and we can only access `lines[0]`, ..., `lines[2]`.)

i.e. `start` parameter just affects `idx` and not `line`.

---

We can use `list slicing` with `enumerate` to access items starting from `cursor` like this:

```
lines = ['line 0', 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', 'line 5', 'line 6']
cursor = 4

for idx, line in enumerate(lines[cursor:], cursor):    # Used slicing: lines[cursor:]
    print(idx, '->', line)
```

Output:

```
4 -> line 4
5 -> line 5
6 -> line 6
```

**But a disadvantage is that `slicing` creates a new list i.e. `not memory efficient`.**

---

An alternative is to use `islice` which does not create a new list i.e. `memory efficient`.

```
from itertools import islice

lines = ['line 0', 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', 'line 5', 'line 6']
cursor = 4

for idx, line in enumerate(
    islice(lines, cursor, len(lines)),    # Used 'islice'
    cursor,
):
    print(idx, '->', line)
```

Output:

```
4 -> line 4
5 -> line 5
6 -> line 6
```

**Read more about `islice` in [Python's Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).**

Comment: wait, so you mean it just changes the start point of enumeration, not of list index?

Comment: Yes! That is true.

Comment: idx will start from the cursor, but item will start from the beginning of the list.

Comment: @KevinSmouts Can I suggest you switch your acceptance to this answer?  (Switched "accepted answer" is allowed.)  This is a much better answer in that a) it explains the problem more clearly; b) it has a memory efficient solution.

Comment: @DipenDadhaniya - this is an amazing answer and explains why my code isn't working.  How can I start an interation at a later line in a file?  Is that even possible?
`def endLine(file, startRow):
    endFile = None
    for num, line in enumerate(file,1):
        if ending in line:
            endFile = num
    return endFile # return this information to caller`

I've tried changing the 1 to startRow, but that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @DataGirl One way of doing it is to use `enumerate(f.readlines()[start_idx:])`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the enumerate optional parameter `start` to set where the enumeration must begin, you need to add your cursor as a starting point to the list parameter like this `lines[cursor:]`

look at this example

```
values = list('abcdefghijkl')

cursor = 3
for idx, val in enumerate(values[cursor:], start=cursor):
    print(idx, val)
```

#### output:

```
3 d
4 e
5 f
6 g
7 h
8 i
9 j
10 k
11 l
```

Comment: you just  gave me the solution: i need to pass the cursor in the list reference with lines[cursor:]. thank you!